# Get Amazon Elasticsearch data in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I'm trying to **retrieve**, **update** and **delete** data from Amazon Elasticsearch. To fetch the data from Amazon Elasticsearch Service I used official [Java API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html) of [www.elastic.co](http://www.elastic.co) but I couldn't figure out whats wrong in my Java code.

Also I'm not expert on AWS. But when I open **search-testing-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-xxxxxxx-1.es.amazonaws.com** url in browser it provides response. Also same url works for all operation in PHP.

If there is another library to connect Amazon Elasticsearch, please provide link with example.

Source code

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;

public class ElasticSearchExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", "34xxxxxxx:testing")
                .put("http.enabled", true).build();

        Client client = TransportClient
                .builder()
                .settings(settings)
                .build()
                .addTransportAddress(
                        new InetSocketTransportAddress(
                                InetAddress
                                        .getByName("search-testing-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-xxxxxxx-1.es.amazonaws.com"),
                                80));

        GetResponse response = client.prepareGet("inventory", "parent", "7874").get();
        System.out.println(response);
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Output

```
Exception in thread "main" NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{xx.xxx.xxx.x}{search-testing-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-xxxxxxx-1.es.amazonaws.com/xx.xxx.xxx.x:80}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:290)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:283)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:347)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:85)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.get(ActionRequestBuilder.java:67)
    at ElasticSearchExample.main(ElasticSearchExample.java:28)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Amazon Elasticsearch service works exclusively over HTTP and you're trying to connect to it via the Transport client which works over TCP.

You can use any other Java HTTP client library, such as the Apache HTTP client or the higher-level Spring's RestTemplate, as shown below

```
// create the REST template
RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate()

// define URL to fetch
String url = "http://search-testing-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-xxxxxxx-1.es.amazonaws.com/inventory/parent/7874";

// make the request
ResponseEntity<String> resp = rest.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class)

// retrieve the JSON response
String body = resp.getBody();
```